# Random errors occur with per-request DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, dbcontext

I'm experiencing random errors (several per day) in my mvc+ef+unity application under higher load (10+ request per sec):

- *The connection was not closed* / *The connection's current state is connecting*
- deadlocks on Count queries (no explicit transaction)
- *An item with the same key has already been added. in System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SetTEntity* while resolving DbContext
- *The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057*
- *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.* - I turned on MARS to get rid off this (altough I believe it should work correctly without MARS, there are no nested queries), which may caused another random error:
- *The server will drop the connection, because the client driver has sent multiple requests while the session is in single-user mode.*

I use [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/02/15/asp-net-mvc-unity-and-common-service-locator.aspx) implementation of PerRequestLifetimeManager and tried Unity.Mvc3 too without any difference.

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518152/the-remote-host-closed-the-connection-the-error-code-is-0x80070057) [hints](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic728749-149-1.aspx#bm802936) that DbContext is not being disposed correctly. I am not sure if per-request is the cause of problems, because it seems to be [common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191797/2075015) practise.

Comment: do you use multi threading anywhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation I found out that request processing thread sometimes steals DbContext from other thread, so Rashid's implementation of PerRequestLifetimeManager may not be thread safe. I moved to Unity.Mvc3 again and the errors disappeared, I must have made some mistake when I tried that last time.

The only error not related were deadlocks. They were caused by collision of

```
SELECT ... FROM X JOIN Y ... JOIN Z ...
```

and

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE Z ...
UPDATE Y ...
COMMIT TRAN
```

SELECT locked Y and wanted Z, TRAN locked Z and wanted Y